# Compute and fill an array in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

As part of a signal processing task, I am doing some computation per frequency step.

I have a **frequencies** list of **length 513**.

I have a 3D numpy array **A** of **shape (81,81,513)**, where 513 is the number of frequency points. I then have a 81x81 matrix per frequency.

I want to apply some modification to each of those matrices, to end up with a modified version of A I'll name **B** here, which will also be of **shape (81,81,513)**.

For that, I start pre-allocating B with :

```
B = np.zeros_like(A)
```

I then loop over my frequencies and call a **dothing** function like:

```
for index, frequency in enumerate(frequencies):
   B[:,:,index] = dothing(A[:,:,index])
```

The problem is that **dothing** takes a lot of time, and ran sequentially over 513 frequency steps seems endless.

So I wanted to parallelize it. But even after reading a lot of docs and watching a lot of videos, I get lost in all the libraries and potential solutions.
Computations at all individual frequencies can be done independently. But in the end I need to assign everything back to B in the right order.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Antoine

Comment: Maybe consider `numba`.

Comment: Are you familiar with how Numpy's broadcasting works, and the concept of vectorizing a function?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by vectorizing a function. Could you give me an exemple please?

As for Numba, my colleagues use it, I'll have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Vectorization is generally about re-writing your function to take better advantage of numpy (think something like `arr.sum(axis=0)` rather than `[sum(sub) for sub in arr]`). Numba is good for numeric functions that require tight fast loops that can't be flattened out with numpy vectorization, and multiprocessing is generally my last resort when both those two can't be made faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I would use a shared array using `shared_memory`, as there's no need to protect write access if no two loop iterations ever use the same memory address. I eliminated the second array to shorten the example (only construct a single shared array), and I re-ordered the array shape to better preserve memory-aligned access.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
from typing import Any
from time import sleep

def dothing(arr: np.ndarray, t_func: Any) -> np.ndarray:
    sleep(.05) #simulate hard work
    return arr * 2

def dodothing(args: tuple[int, Any]):
    global arr
    index = args[0]
    t_func = args[1]
    arr[index] = dothing(arr[index], t_func) #write result back to self to avoid need for 2 shared arrays

def init(shm: SharedMemory, shape: tuple[int, ...], dtype: npt.DTypeLike):
    global arr
    arr = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _A = np.ones((513,81,81), np.float64) #source data

    t_funcs = ["some transfer function"] * _A.shape[0] #added example of passing some data + an index

    nbytes = _A.size * _A.itemsize
    dtype = _A.dtype
    shape = _A.shape

    shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=nbytes)

    A = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)

    A[:] = _A[:] #copy contents into shared A

    with Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(shm, shape, dtype)) as pool:
        pool.map(dodothing, enumerate(t_funcs)) #enumerate returns tuple[int,Any] each loop

    print(A.sum()/_A.sum()) #prove we multiplied all elements by 2

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

`multiprocessing.Pool` is a bit funny sometimes in what can be a valid argument to a target function, so I tend to share things like `Lock`, `Queue`, `shared_memory` etc. via the pool's initialization function, which accepts arguments just like `Process` does.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer Aaron!

I am trying to implement it at the moment. But one thing I omitted is that the dothing function also takes a fixed list of arrays (transfer functions) in addition to A.
This list has a length equal to the number of frequency points (i.e. = to 3rd dimension of A). It's a list of 2D arrays basically.

I tried passing it as well to the .map method but it doesn't work. Basically it should go as a second argument to dothing.

Any idea how you would do that?

Thanks again.

Comment: `map` works with functions that accept only a single input. see edit for passing multiple args (there are many ways to do it...)

Comment: Thank you @Aaron! I modified my script as per your last input.
It seems to work well and to fasten up everything.

But at the end, after the last frequency point is processed by one of the child processes, I get the following error message:

Comment: ----------------------------------
Windows fatal exception: access violation


Main thread:
Thread 0x00000610 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 734 in recv_multipart
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 606 in _handle_recv

Comment: File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 577 in _handle_events
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 661 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 741 in _run_callback
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80 in _run

Comment: File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890 in _run_once
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601 in run_forever
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199 in start
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 711 in start
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 340 in main

Comment: File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87 in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\APU\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197 in _run_module_as_main


Restarting kernel...
----------------------------------

Comment: Any idea where this might come from? (sorry for the multi-comment)

Comment: trying to access the shared array after the shared memory is `close()`'d will cause a c level error (segfault on posix, and access violation on windows). If it's in the global space the vairable explorer in spyder will try to access it, and cause this exception

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand you're point but I don't really know how to solve that though.
How can I keep my A array to pass it to the rest of my code (after multiprocessing treatment) without having this error?

Comment: Not closing files can technically lead to memory leaks (memory mapped files may live until your computer is next rebooted), or in some cases will only live until the interpreter is closed. If that's relatively fine with you, just skip `shm.close()` and `shm.unlink()`. That way the data should be accessible in the interactive interpreter after executing your code. Alternatively you can copy the data out of `A` into another array, or just do all your processing in one script, and make sure the shm is not closed until you're done needing `A`

Comment: Hi @Aaron

Thanks again so much for your help!
I works on my end, so I marked your answer as "accepted".

I still have trouble understanding the role of A however. Is it not redundant with the definition of arr in the init function? I don't see how A can be updated as there is no apparent link with the rest and it is not passed to Pool in the context.

Comment: `arr` as defined in `init` only exists in each child worker processes because `init` is not called in the main process anywhere (globals don't cross between processes). The shared memory is an operating system resource which is a memory-mapped file sitting in RAM (not on disk generally). This is shared with the child processes by filename (passing `shm` via `initargs` internally only sends the filename). This is how the same resource is accessed by both processes. The numpy array is reading and writing to the same memory mapped file which is open in several processes.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Aaron for the detailed explanation.